# How to write cmd shim for msbuild?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

People in my office often ask me 'how do I run those tests?'. I tell them, browse to the Build folder, open a command prompt, and run `msbuild /t:Tests`.

That works for me, because msbuild is in my path

```
> where msbuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

However it doesn't work for everyone else, because they might not have that folder in their path. Explaining how to change that is tedious.

Is it possible to make the command work for everyone, even if they don't have the folder in their path?

I'm imagining a file `msbuild.cmd` in the Build folder that fixes the problem. It would run the real `msbuild.exe` with the *same arguments* (it's not always `/t:Tests`). It would first look in the path for `msbuild.exe`, then in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`.

Comment: Sure...Just tell them the full path of the exe and include that in the command you tell them.  Infact forget about the path file if you simply did `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /t:Tests` it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Went with

```
@echo off
REM This shim helps anyone who doesn't have msbuild in their path.

for %%X in (msbuild.exe) do (
    msbuild.exe %*
    exit /b
)

echo "You should probably add msbuild to your path."

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" %*
exit /b
```

Comment: if the last part relays the arguments to the exe file, what does the `for %%X` part do ?